# Error in SchedularCallBack while creating windows services

Tags: c#, sql, windows-services

I tried everything. Looked at all the previous similar questions (almost 14k of them) but couldn't fine a solution.

I am not able to connect to my DB from my service. Here's the error

```
Simple Service Error on: 16/06/2018 11:50:00 PM Login failed for user 'LAPTOP-84OBORRF\sriva'.
```

and the trace goes on and ends at

```
at WindowsServiceCS.Service1.SchedularCallback(Object e) in D:\Projects\WindowsService_SendEmail\WindowsServiceCS\Service1.cs:line 113
```

This is my connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="constr" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=VMS.Models.ApplicationDbContext; User Id=LAPTOP-84OBORRF\sriva; Password = 1234; "/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

and finally here's my schedular function

```
try
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string query = "SELECT Name, EmailAdress FROM VolunteerInfoes WHERE DATEPART(DAY, BirthdayDateTime) = @Day AND DATEPART(MONTH, BirthdayDateTime) = @Month";
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day", DateTime.Today.Day);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", DateTime.Today.Month);
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                sda.Fill(dt); //The error is in this line
            }
        }
    }
    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        string name = row["Name"].ToString();
        string email = row["EmailAdress"].ToString();
        WriteToFile("Trying to send email to: " + name + " " + email);

        using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("srivastava.anan@gmail.com", email))
        {
            mm.Subject = "Birthday Greetings";
            mm.Body = string.Format("<b>Happy Birthday </b>{0}<br /><br />Many happy returns of the day.", name);

            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
            credentials.UserName = "srivastava.anan@gmail.com";
            credentials.Password = "footube@-321";
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = credentials;
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Send(mm);
            WriteToFile("Email sent successfully to: " + name + " " + email);
        }
    }
    this.ScheduleService();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    WriteToFile("Simple Service Error on: {0} " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);

    //Stop the Windows Service.
    using (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController serviceController = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("SimpleService"))
    {
        serviceController.Stop();
    }
}
```

In my created service, could any one tell me if the account password and the password at the connection string need to be same or not? That is, 
[image]

this password and the password in the connection string? Thanks.

**EDIT**

[image: DB Image]

Connection String shown when i click on properties of my DB

```
Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=VMS.Models.ApplicationDbContext;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

**Solutions I tried from previous answers,**

Added

```
 <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  </system.web>
```

or changed `Integrated security to False to specify user id and password.`

Tried many other solutions but couldn't get it working. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: a) does it work when you run as normal process (not service) ?

Comment: b) what is missing is the configuration of the sql server, does it allow user/password?

Comment: @HenkHolterman : Thank you so much for replying.  I am a beginner and I am not sure what you're trying to ask. I am using the inbuilt server in the Visual Studio. To answer your second question, I think it does allow user name and password. Please look at my updated question.  As for your first question, I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Kindly ask me for any more information that you need. Thank you for helping.

Comment: "Connection String shown when .." - in the same window, see what the Authentican Mode and maybe related settings are.

Comment: A service is very hard to debug so you will want a second project to test and debug parts or all of your code. Create a Console project and try to connect to your Db.

Comment: Authentication mode is "mixed" and the rest of the settings seem fine. I'll create a console application to test the connection and get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was specifying a Windows account and password in the connection string. That is not permitted; those are used only for authentication using a SQL account. So I added "Integrated Security=SSPI" to the connection string and removed the User ID and Password and my problem was solved.